# Skip archive and export when running cordova build ios

Tags: ios, cordova, build

I am debugging something that must be built to a live device and trying to shorten the time it takes to iterate. I noticed at first that running `cordova build ios` would just do the build, and the last message I see would be **** BUILD SUCCEEDED ****. Later on, however—I'm not sure what changed—but whenever I run the same command it will do a build + archive + export. How can I cut out the latter two, archive and export?